# The arithmetic operation returns -nan(ind)

Tags: c

When calculating S from a given equality within [0; π/2] with a step of π/20, the return value is -nan(ind) by x = π/20 and subsequent. What could be the problem?

[image: The equality]

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi       3.1415926535f
#define start    0
#define end      pi / 2
#define delta    pi / 20
#define accuracy powf(10, -6)

float factorial(float number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int c = 0;
    float factorial = 1;
    for (c = 1; c <= number; c++)
    {
        factorial *= c;
    }
    return(factorial);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int k = 0;
    float x = 0, y = 0, s = 0;
    printf("1 - Аргумент (x)\n2 - Значение функции y(x)\n3 - Сумма (s)\n4 - Количество итераций (k)\n\n+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+\n|      1      |      2      |      3      |      4      |\n+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+\n");
    for (x = start; x <= end; x += delta)
    {
        do
        {
            k++;
            s += powf(-1, k + 1) * ((powf(2, 2 * k - 1) * powf(x, 2 * k)) / (factorial(2 * k)));
        } while (fabs(s) >= accuracy);
        s = 1 - s;
        y = powf(cos(x), 2);
        printf("| %11.6f | %11.6f | %11.6f | %11i |\n+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+\n", x, y, s, k);
        s = 0;
        k = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console:

In the first column is the value of `x`, in the second - the value of the function `y(x)`, in the third - the value of `s`, in the fourth - the `k` (count) of iterations during the calculation of the series.

```
1 - Аргумент (x)
2 - Значение функции y(x)
3 - Сумма (s)
4 - Количество итераций (k)

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      1      |      2      |      3      |      4      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,000000 |    1,000000 |    1,000000 |           1 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,157080 |    0,975528 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,314159 |    0,904509 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,471239 |    0,793893 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,628319 |    0,654509 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,785398 |    0,500000 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    0,942478 |    0,345491 |   -nan(ind) |          65 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1,099557 |    0,206107 |   -nan(ind) |          57 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1,256637 |    0,095491 |   -nan(ind) |          49 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1,413717 |    0,024472 |   -nan(ind) |          44 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I suspect it is because `∞ ÷ ∞ → NaN`.  Side note: `float` is great for storing big amounts of floating point data more efficiently, at some loss of precision.  `double` is great for doing calculations.

Comment: Debug the output of `k` keep in mind that the factorial of 35 is already more than the minimum of `FLT_MAX` (i.e. when k reaches 18, you get an overflow). Using `double` could help a bit, but even a `double` could overflow for your application.

Comment: Why are you even using `float` for math? **Never** use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C.

Comment: @Ivanov Vladislav, why `float` objects yet `double` functions?

Comment: Never compute power series literally. Notice that the ratio of subsequent terms is `-(1/4) * x * x /((2k+1) * (2k+2))`, and don't bother with powers and factorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i add the line `if(k>18) { printf("k is too big: %i\n",k); }`  in your `do`-`while`-loop, this warning gets printed. a `k` of 19 means you want to calculate the factorial of `38`, which is about `5.23022617e44`, and too large for a 32 bit `float`. And therefore you can not get the correct result.
The other overflow you get is in `powf(x, 2 * k)`, which can also reach values `>FLT_MAX` with your values.

Why is `number` a `float`? Wouldn't a `unsigned` make more sense? Similar why is `k` and `c` signed?